# Using styled-components with props and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, styled-components

I'm trying to integrate TypeScript into our project and so far I stumbled upon one issue with [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) library.

Consider this component

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

// -- types ----------------------------------------------------------------- //
export interface Props {
  onPress: any;
  src: any;
  width: string;
  height: string;
}

// -- styling --------------------------------------------------------------- //
const Icon = styled.Image`
  width: ${(p: Props) => p.width};
  height: ${(p: Props) => p.height};
`;

class TouchableIcon extends React.Component<Props> {
  // -- default props ------------------------------------------------------- //
  static defaultProps: Partial<Props> = {
    src: null,
    width: "20px",
    height: "20px"
  };

  // -- render -------------------------------------------------------------- //
  render() {
    const { onPress, src, width, height } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <Icon source={src} width={width} height={height} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default TouchableIcon;
```

Following line throws 3 errors, that are same in nature `<Icon source={src} width={width} height={height} />`

> Type {source: any; width: string; height: string;} is not assignable
> to type IntrinsicAttributes ... Property 'onPress' is missing in type
> {source: any; width: string; height: string;}

Not entirely sure what this is and how to fix it, do I somehow need to declare these on `Icon` or something of this sort?

**EDIT:** typescript `v2.6.1`, styled-components `v2.2.3`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**This answer is outdated, the most current answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045733/1053772**

As far as I can tell there is no official way (yet?) to do this, but you can solve it with a bit of trickery. First, create a `withProps.ts` file with the following content:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { ThemedStyledFunction } from 'styled-components'

const withProps = <U>() => <P, T, O>(fn: ThemedStyledFunction<P, T, O>) =>
    fn as ThemedStyledFunction<P & U, T, O & U>

export { withProps }
```

Now, inside your `.tsx` files, use it like this:

```
// ... your other imports
import { withProps } from './withProps'

export interface IconProps {
  onPress: any;
  src: any;
  width: string;
  height: string;
}

const Icon = withProps<IconProps>()(styled.Image)`
  width: ${(p: IconProps) => p.width};
  height: ${(p: IconProps) => p.height};
`;
```

And you should be good to go. It's definitely *not* ideal and hopefully there will be a way to provide generics to template literals soon in TS, but I guess that for now this is your best option.

Credit is given where credit is due: I copypasted this from [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/630)

Comment: This was a great solution, but @elnygren's comment below is definitely the most elegant current solution.

Answer (score 205):

There have been some recent developments and with a new version of Typescript (eg. 3.0.1) and styled-components (eg. 3.4.5) there's no need for a separate helper. You can specify the interface/type of your props to styled-components directly.

```
interface Props {
  onPress: any;
  src: any;
  width: string;
  height: string;
}

const Icon = styled.Image<Props>`
  width: ${p => p.width};
  height: ${p => p.height};
`;
```

and if you want to be more precise and ignore the `onPress`

```
const Icon = styled.Image<Pick<Props, 'src' | 'width' | 'height'>>`
  width: ${p => p.width};
  height: ${p => p.height};
`;
```

Comment: Neat! Works well with themes too. This should be the selected answer. Only problem is it breaks my syntax highlighting...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `styled.image<Props>`?

Comment: @ManuRauck I don't agree. 

Type {source: any; width: string; height: string;} is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes ... Property 'onPress' is missing in type {source: any; width: string; height: string;}

onPress is clearly missing, so onPress is a prop of Image

Comment: Can anyone recommend the solution to make Typescript accept keyframes with params?

Comment: Can use styled.Image<Omit<Props, 'onPress'>>` which is a lil shorter

Answer (score 20):

The easiest way as styled-components [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) said:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Header from './Header';

const NewHeader = styled(Header)<{ customColor: string }>`
  color: ${(props) => props.customColor};
`;
// Header will also receive props.customColor
```

Answer (score 13):

styled-component

```
    import styled from 'styled-components';

interface Props {
    height: number;
}

export const Wrapper = styled.div<Props>`
    padding: 5%;
    height: ${(props) => props.height}%;
`;
```

index

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { Wrapper } from './Wrapper';

interface Props {
    className?: string;
    title: string;
    height: number;
}

export const MainBoardList: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ className, title, height }) => (
    <Wrapper height={height} className={className}>
        {title}
    </Wrapper>
);
```

should work

Answer (score 6):

You need only specify a `interface`:

```
import { createGlobalStyle, css } from 'styled-components';

interface PropsGlobalStyle {
  dark: boolean
}

export default createGlobalStyle`
  ${({ dark }: PropsGlobalStyled) => css`
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: ${dark ? '#fff' : '#000'};
      background-color: ${dark ? '#000' : '#fff'};
    }
  `};
`;
```

Answer (score 6):

An example using `ColorCard` with color prop

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const ColorCard = styled.div<{ color: string }>`
  background-color: ${({ color }) => color};
`;
```

Comment: it is amazing, thanks

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @elnygren worked for me. Just one question from me. How to assign a default value to the following code (copied from the answer of @elnygren). e.g. If I do not want to pass any value to the 'width' and 'height' a default value will be used.

```
const Icon = styled.Image<Pick<Props, 'src' | 'width' | 'height'>>`
  width: ${p => p.width};
  height: ${p => p.height};
`;
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30053638)

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling through this myself, but I think the problem is that you are using the Props interface inside the styled component. Try creating another interface with just the image props and use that in your styled component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

// -- types ----------------------------------------------------------------- //
export interface Props {
  onPress: any;
  src: any;
  width: string;
  height: string;
}


export interface ImageProps {
  src: string;
  width: string;
  height: string;
}

// -- styling --------------------------------------------------------------- //
const Icon = styled.Image`
  width: ${(p: ImageProps ) => p.width};
  height: ${(p: ImageProps ) => p.height};
`;

class TouchableIcon extends React.Component<Props> {
  // -- default props ------------------------------------------------------- //
  static defaultProps: Partial<Props> = {
    src: null,
    width: "20px",
    height: "20px"
  };

  // -- render -------------------------------------------------------------- //
  render() {
    const { onPress, src, width, height } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <Icon source={src} width={width} height={height} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default TouchableIcon;
```

Seems to work but I hate to have to duplicate those interfaces. Hopefully someone else can show the correct way or maybe embedding the ImageProps into Props?

Comment: This didn't work for me, but tmp workaround is `const Icon: any = styled.Image` I have no idea why it works, however

Comment: Glad you got it to work, that worked for me as well. I am in react-dom so maybe there is some difference there.

Comment: that's what I needed: `width: ${(p: ImageProps ) => p.width};`

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props) state:

> If you want to prevent props meant to be consumed by styled components from being passed to the underlying React node or rendered to the DOM element, you can prefix the prop name with a dollar sign ($), turning it into a transient prop.