# How to type a styled component without losing any prop with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm new to styled components and I'd like to be able to type my styled components correctly so that when I pass props "vs code" I can autodetect all those props I have, not just the one in the theme or the ones I could put with an interface.

Would there be any way without using a HOC for it as I've seen in some other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077210/using-styled-components-with-props-and-typescript)? Is it possible to get a general prop to use in all without having to be defining in each property of style this as in the example?

> app.theme.ts

```
export const theme = {
  palette: {
    primaryColor: '#FF5018',
    secondaryColor: '#252729',
    tertiaryColor: '#1A1C1E',
    textColor: 'white',
  },
};

export type Theme = typeof theme;
```

> navigation-bar.styled.component.ts

```
export const NavigationBarStyled = styled.div`
  grid-area: navigation-bar-item;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.primaryColor};
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.primaryColor};
`;
```

Thanks in advance,
Best

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be solved as @Huy-Nguyen said but in practice, you lose properties on Styled Components or you have to define the same many times.

So the best option is this as the Styled-Components website says (to define a theme interface):

> theme.ts

```
export default interface ThemeInterface {
  primaryColor: string;
  primaryColorInverted: string;
}
```

> styled-components.ts

```
import * as styledComponents from "styled-components";

import ThemeInterface from "./theme";

const {
  default: styled,
  css,
  createGlobalStyle,
  keyframes,
  ThemeProvider
} = styledComponents as styledComponents.ThemedStyledComponentsModule<ThemeInterface>;

export { css, createGlobalStyle, keyframes, ThemeProvider };
export default styled;
```

And then, you use that:

```
import styled from 'app/styled-components';

// theme is now fully typed
const Title = styled.h1`
  color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor};
`;
```

Just pass the link: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#define-a-theme-interface

Thank you so much for all.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason (possibly due to the way `styled-components`'s typescript definition is written), the typing for `Theme` works if you remove one of level of nesting. This snippet typechecks with no error for me (v4) i.e. typescript knows that `primaryColor` is a `string`:

```js
const theme = {
  primaryColor: '#FF5018',
  secondaryColor: '#252729',
  tertiaryColor: '#1A1C1E',
  textColor: 'white',
};

type Theme = typeof theme;

type Props = Theme & {
  // ... other keys
}

const NavigationBarStyled = styled.div<Props>`
  grid-area: navigation-bar-item;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: ${props => props.primaryColor};
  background-color: ${props => props.primaryColor};
`;
```

Comment: Hi @Huy-Nguyen, thank you for the answer but with this implementation of Props you don't lose other properties about Styled Components or React? Because you reduce the possibilities simply to have either theme properties or the custom ones you enter or not?

Comment: And... Is it possible to call accessories once to use them all? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We approached this is a different way.
*<sub>NOTE: Styled Components v5 with React Native</sub>*

- Define your theme type.

  ```js
  // MyTheme.ts

  export type MyTheme = {
    colors: {
      primary: string;
      background: string;
    };
  };
  ```
- Use the type on your themes.

  ```js
  // themes.ts

  export const LightTheme: MyTheme = {
    colors: {
      primary: 'white',
      background: 'white',
    },
  };

  export const DarkTheme: MyTheme = {
    colors: {
      primary: 'grey',
      background: 'black',
    },
  };
  ```
- Use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to "merge" the MyTheme type into Styled Components default theme.

  ```js
  // styled.d.ts

  import 'styled-components';
  import { MyTheme } from '../src/themes/MyTheme';

  declare module 'styled-components' {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
    export interface DefaultTheme extends MyTheme {}
  }
  ```

OK, cool. The `theme` prop is correctly typed.
What about the components themselves?

- Wrap your specific component props in the `StyledProps` type.

  ```js
  import { StyledProps } from 'styled-components';
  import styled from 'styled-components/native';

  type MyViewProps = StyledProps<{
    backgroundColor?: string;
    isAlert?: boolean;
  }>;

  const MyView = styled.View(
    (props: MyViewProps) => `
      background-color: ${props.backgroundColor || props.theme.colors.background};
      color: ${props.isAlert ? red : props.theme.colors.primary}
    `,
  );
  ```

In this example both `props.backgroundColor` and `props.theme.colors.background` will auto-complete. When you update `MyTheme` type or the specific component type it should just work.

[image: component auto-complete]

[image: them auto-complete]

Comment: I swear this approach has always worked for me. But something in the current project I'm working on is different and all I'm seeing for the type on `props` is `any`. The only thing I'm doing different is I'm using `StyledComponentsThemeProvider`. Do you have any ideas why I'm just getting any on props?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best method. But I found a solution as follows.

```
// theme.ts
const theme = {
  colors: {
     ...
  }
};
export type themeTypes = typeof theme;
export default theme;


// styled.d.ts ( in root folder )
import 'styled-components'
import { themeTypes } from '@/styles/theme'

declare module 'styled-components' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface DefaultTheme extends themeTypes {}
}
```