# Why can't I pass props when I use "input type" in React + Styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am learning React.
I want to use styled-components to style "input type".
I can expand props with normal  "input type".
But when I use styled-components, it doesn't work..
props are passed from the parent component.

```ts
import * as React from "react";
import { Input } from "./style";

export const Field: React.FC<React.ComponentProps<"input">> = (
  props: React.ComponentProps<"input">
) => (
  <>
      {/*　work */}
　　　　{/* <input {...props} type={"text"} /> */}

      {/*　it doesn't work.. */}
      <Input {...props} type={"text"} />     
  </>
);
```

style.ts

```ts
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Input = styled.input`
 //style
`;
```

Comment: It seems to work when "input" is set to "any"...

Comment: How did you define the Input component?

Comment: Thank you. I added above.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077210/using-styled-components-with-props-and-typescript

Answer (score 1):

The problem is native `input` and `Input` have incompatible `ref` property types. While native `input` `ref` has type

```ts
LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined
```

`styled-components` wrapped `Input` has `ref` type

```ts
((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined
```

You may just omit this property if you're not going to pass it to the component:

```ts
export const Field: React.FC<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"input">> = (
  props
) => (
    <Input {...props} type="text" />
);
```

or type it correctly:

`@types/react@17.x` version:

```ts
type Props = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"input"> & { ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement> }

export const Field: React.FC<Props> = (props) => (
  <Input {...props} type="text" />
);
```

`@types/react@16.x` version:

```ts
// there is no exported ForwardedRef type and we have to define it oursevles
type ForwardedRef<T> = ((instance: T | null) => void) | React.MutableRefObject<T | null> | null
type Props = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"input"> & { ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement> }

export const Field: React.FC<Props> = (props) => (
  <Input {...props} type="text" />
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved it with the above solution.
But "type it correctly:" is
Namespace'React' has no exported member'forwardRef'.

Comment: Updated the answer to account for `@types/react@16.x`.