# How can I get alternate image of array of images with different height using grid or flex?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, css-grid, styled-components

I have array of object ImageKist where I would like to show alternate image with different heights using grid or flex as shown below:[image]

How can I achieve above pattern using grid or flex?

Install styled-component as follow:
npm install --save styled-components

Current result is as below where images should come from left to right where I have used grid but its fine if we get the desired result with flex. [image]

Below is my code with alternate images:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
const imageList = [
{
  id: "1",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
},
{
  id: "2",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
},
{
  id: "3",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
},
{
  id: "4",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551009175-8a68da93d5f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80",
},
{
  id: "5",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
},
{
  id: "6",
  url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg",
},
{
  id: "7",
  url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg",
},
{
  id: "8",
  url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg",
},
];

return (
<Wrapper>
  {imageList.map((image: any, index) => (
    <>
      {index % 2 === 0 ? (
        <ImageWrapper key={image.id}>
          <ImageStyled src={image.url} alt={image.url} />
          <H4Styled>{image.id}</H4Styled>
        </ImageWrapper>
      ) : (
        <ImageWrapper1 key={image.id}>
          <ImageStyled src={image.url} alt={image.url} />
          <H4Styled>{image.id}</H4Styled>
        </ImageWrapper1>
      )}
    </>
  ))}
</Wrapper>
);
};

export default App;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 80px;
gap: 30px;
`;

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
grid-row: span 2;
`;

const ImageWrapper1 = styled.div`
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
grid-row: span 3;
`;

const ImageStyled = styled.img`
min-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 20px;
`;

const H4Styled = styled.h4`
position: absolute;
top: 16px;
color: white;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Only quickly tested but this seems to work for me in TypeScript:

```
interface ImageWrapperProps {
  index: number;
}
```

And apply the `interface` to the component using `index` as prop:

```
const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-row: ${({ index }: ImageWrapperProps) =>
    (index + 1) % 2 === 0 ? 'span 3' : 'span 2'};
  grid-column: ${({ index }: ImageWrapperProps) =>
    (index + 2) % 6 === 0 ? '2' : 'auto'};
`;
```

It probably depends on configurations, so if it does not work perhaps also reference some suggestions to use TypeScriptt with `styled-components` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47077210/20436957).

Also if not done yet perhaps try install `@types/styled-components` in the project:

```
npm install @types/styled-components
```

**Original**

It seems that the [props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) of `styled-components` can be used to simplify the logic and also manage the placement of images based on the `index`.

The below example pass the `index` as prop to `ImageWrapper` and change the `grid-row` and `grid-column` based on `index` as a condition, so there is no need to define 2 components for it.

The current condition works for a 3 column image list, but it can be adjusted in the styles to fit other layout, if needed.

Simplified live demo of example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x63yfw?file=src/App.js)

Perhaps try:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 80px;
gap: 30px;
grid-auto-flow: row dense;
`;

//  Use prop here to change style by condition
const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border-radius: 20px;
grid-row: ${({ index }) => ((index + 1) % 2 === 0 ? 'span 3' : 'span 2')};
grid-column: ${({ index }) => ((index + 2) % 6 === 0 ? '2' : 'auto')};
`;

const ImageStyled = styled.img`
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
`;

const H4Styled = styled.h4`
position: absolute;
top: 16px;
color: white;
`;
```

And in the output:

```
<Wrapper>
  {imageList.map((image, index) => (
    <ImageWrapper key={image.id} index={index}>
      <ImageStyled src={image.url} alt={image.url} />
      <H4Styled>{image.id}</H4Styled>
    </ImageWrapper>
  ))}
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: @TruptiGaonkar My bad, did not notice that TypeScript is also needed. I updated the answer with what works for me in TypeScript, although it might also depends on config but hopefully it could help. Perhaps also try some other methods from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47077210/20436957).